# Texturing GL_QUADS with (3x3) color array ignores the 4th color in each row

Tags: arrays, opengl, texture-mapping

I'm trying to generate a 3x3 texture from an byte array.

My problem is i need to give one extra color in the final of each row to get what I want, and i want to know why.

Is there a problem in the byte count that I'm ignoring or something like that?

Here's my array:

```
GLubyte data[33] = { 
                    //bottom row
                    0, 0, 150,
                    150, 10, 220,
                    150, 150, 56,

                    0, 0, 0,        //must be here to get what I want but don't render

                    //middle row
                    150, 150, 150,
                    150, 0, 21,
                    0, 255, 0,

                    0, 0, 0,        //must be here to get what I want but don't render

                    //top row
                    250, 150, 0,
                    250, 0, 150,
                    0, 150, 0 };
```

And my texture generation:

```
GLuint texture;

glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

//I thing the problem is right here
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

return texture;
```

And I'm applying the texture like this:

```
GLuint texture = genTexture(0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
glEnd();
```

And the result is ignoring these 24 bits for each row:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` pixel storage parameter to make this work:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

This controls the alignment of rows in the data passed to `glTexImage2D()`. The default values is 4. In your case, since each row consists of 9 bytes of data (3 colors with 3 bytes each), an alignment value of 4 would round up the row size to 12. This means that 12 bytes will be read per row, and explains why it works when you add an extra 3 bytes at the end of each row.

With the alignment set to 1, you will not need extra padding.

Comment: Yeah thats it! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate your environment's value for the `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` pixel-store parameter. [The manual](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml) says:

> `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`
>
> Specifies the alignment requirements for the start of each pixel row in memory. The allowable values are 1 (byte-alignment), 2 (rows aligned to even-numbered bytes), 4 (word-alignment), and 8 (rows start on double-word boundaries).

That manual page says that the "initial value" is, indeed, `4`.

Use a suitable [`glGetInteger()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGet.xhtml) call to read out the value.

Comment: Oh! really thank you! if my image is 4x4 (or multiple) it works very well! I finally understand how it works, all I need to change is my ['glPixelStore()'](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) right?

Comment: @CapitanNeptune I can't guarantee much, but that's certainly the first thing I think you should try, yes.

Comment: Note that this is the wrong value. `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` is used for transfers **to** client memory, e.g. `glReadPixels()`. `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` is the setting used for transfers **from** client memory, like `glTexImage2D()`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Gaah, thanks, that's very n00b of me. Obviously it's been to long since I used OpenGL. I'll edit, of course. The quoted text is from the proper constant, but I managed to use the wrong constant name here. D'oh.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. I had provided a correct answer just in case.